# HTTP session transfer

Tags: http, session

My question is as follows:

1. A site is hosted on multiple web servers, all servers refer to same domain.
2. Sometimes, users login to a central server, but get re-directed to other web servers.
3. Since domain is the same, cookies will be sent from browser to the new servers.
4. But server side (uses JSPs) session related data will nto be present at the second server.

So, will the second server accept this as an existing session, or, will it deem that there is no session?

For my own reasons, I had to stick to single session, multiple servers approach. This is basically for a game like evony.com, with multiple realms hosted on multiple machines possibly. Login happens once, but same session will be used in multiple server machines. Please let me know.

Comment: I am using Tomcat, and assigning sessionId using session.setAttribute("sessionId", ....); call. My question is whether server store anything to identify that some connection etc... is in a session, and does it use that to cross-verify.

Comment: You can define your custom session handler and store sessions in DB that is accessible by all servers.